# How do I calculate the Network from an IP?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following IP address (example): `195.65.254.11`

I am looking to construct a set of queries (or functions) to return the network this IP belongs to (which is `195.65.254.0/24`)

I started by converting the IP into a integer:

```
create function [dbo].[IPAddressToInteger] (@IP as varchar(15))
returns bigint
as
begin
 return (convert(bigint, parsename(@IP,1)) +
         convert(bigint, parsename(@IP,2)) * 256 +
         convert(bigint, parsename(@IP,3)) * 256 * 256 +
         convert(bigint, parsename(@IP,4)) * 256 * 256 * 256)
end

select dbo.IPAddressToInteger('195.65.254.11'); -- 3275881995
```

Then I calculated the CIDR:

```
create function [dbo].[CIDRFromMask] (@mask as bigint)
returns varchar(5)
as
begin
     declare @maskCalc bigint
     select  @maskCalc = dbo.IPAddressToInteger('255.255.255.255') - @mask + 1

     declare @logCalc int
     select  @logCalc = (32 - log(@maskCalc, 2))

     return '/' + cast(@logCalc as varchar(5))
end

select dbo.CIDRFromMask('3275881995'); -- /2
```

But here I am stuck. How do I continue to **retrieve the correct network**?

Comment: You can't, those are two distinct pieces of information, you can't calculate one from the other. If you could, then you wouldn't need to specify it.

Comment: But I downloaded an GeoIP database which has only one distinctive column `network` in which it lists networks like `1.0.0.0/24` (and in this example, `195.65.254.0/24`). How do I match a users IP address against such a table then, so that I can return the country from which they connect?

Comment: You will have to query all possible networks based on your calculation and use the end of the range to determine in which one your ip falls. In worst case you have to iterate over 32 results.

Comment: But if this is true, then how do they do it here? http://jodies.de/ipcalc?host=195.65.254.11&mask1=24&mask2=

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table of networks, store the start and stop ranges as columns.  For example:

```
Network      Start      Stop        Name
1.0.0.0/24   1.0.0.0    1.0.0.255   Some guy
```

(In reality, `Start` and `Stop` would be stored as integers, but for this example I am showing dotted-quad)

To query the network to which an address belongs, you use `BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT n.Network, n.Name
FROM Networks n
WHERE @TargetAddress BETWEEN n.Start and n.Stop
```

(Again, insert calls to `IPAddressToInteger` as appropriate)

To generate the `Start` and `Stop` values from a network address and mask, use the following formulas.

```
Start = Network Address
Stop  = Network Address | (~Subnet Mask)
```

IPv6 can be trivially accomidated in this design by using 64 bit integers under the assumption that no globally routable network will use a prefix longer than 64 bits (which I think is the case, but am currently too lazy to verify).

The advantage of using `BETWEEN` with `Start` and `Stop` is that the query is able to take advantage of indexes you create, as compared to the naïve query which would use `WHERE NetworkAddress = @Address & NetworkSubnet`.